# Android Socket Getting Hanged

Tags: android, sockets

I have Created a Service Which in turn Creates a Socket, But as soon as try to read data sent from Server, it hangs ,On the other hand the same code run if i am not using Service but plain Activity ??

```
        import android.app.*;
        import android.content.*;
        import android.os.*;
        import android.util.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import java.io.*;
        import android.widget.*;




     public class BackgroundService extends Service
            {
                    private Socket socket=null;
                    private  InputStreamReader  in=null;
                    private String ip;

                    private String tag="BackgroundService";

                    public IBinder onBind(Intent p1)
                    {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            return null;
                    }

             public void onCreate(){
                     super.onCreate();




             }
            public void onStart(Intent i,int id){
             super.onStart(i,id);
                    ip=i.getStringExtra("Ip");

             Log.v(tag,"Ip "+i.getStringExtra("Ip"));
                    try
                    {
                            socket = new Socket(ip.trim(), 8888);
                            new Runnable() {

                                    public void run()
                                    { 
//                                        Hangs in this block.....
                                            try
                                            {
                                                    in = new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream());
                                            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader (in);
        //                                 Never Reaches this messge
                                            Log.v(tag,"mess:"+bf.readLine() );
                                            }
                                            catch (IOException e)
                                            {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                            }


                                    }


                            }.run();



                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            }

            }
```

Comment: Did the Socket connect properly? So did the thread enter the run method at all? Furthermore, try to open the output stream first. There was an issue in Java concerning Object...Streams but I'm not sure if it will fix your problem. BTW, why are you using a Runnable but invoke it synchronous? Did you want to use a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)?

Comment: Yes the Socket connect properly, even if i don't use runable its the same, ill try to call outputstream first then inputstream

Comment: Finally figured out the flaw its in Log.v, Using System.out.println works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log.v is the Problem it wont allow you print the value so use System.out.println() and bf.printline will contain the message